# Data extracted from Textbox is not the same as excel data

Tags: vba, symbols

I have a Textbox `multiline=true`
I use formula `Split` that Textbox but string in textbox can not vlookup value because that is string symbol special.

Comment: You need to share your code and show some examples of the **before** and **after** product of your macro. Then others can help you. As of right now, we don't really know what the problem is which is the *likely* reason that nobody has provided a solution.

Comment: Please help me with code below.

Comment: Add code to your question. You added your code as a solution -

Comment: I have values in textbox
MBY001
MBY002
MBY003
MBY004
I use split to get value in 
Cells(1,"A").value=MBY001
Cells(2,"A").value=MBY002
Cells(3,"A").value=MBY003
Cells(3,"A").value=MBY004
After I get value column A by use fomular below but values from MBY001->MBY004 cannot vlookup data in excelalthough that value exists in the spreadsheet

Answer (score 1):

This is your code,
please check help me.

Sub CommandButton22_Click()

```
With Sheet2
    If Trim(TextBox21.Text) <> "" Then
        If UBound(Split(TextBox21.Text, Chr(10))) > 0 Then
            For i = 0 To UBound(Split(CStr(TextBox21.Text), Chr(10)))
            Dim a As String
               a = Trim(CStr(Split(TextBox21.Text, Chr(10))(i)))
                If IsEmpty(a) = False Then
                .Cells(1 + i, "A").Value = Trim(CStr(a))
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    End If
End With
```

End Sub